# Using Golang Gin with AWS Lambda and Serverless with proxy path

Tags: go, aws-lambda, go-gin

I want to proxy all my HTTP requests from root through a single lambda function call.
I tried setting `/{proxy+}` as the path in my serverless.yml.  But when I deploy it I get "This page isn't redirecting properly" when visiting the root.

serverless.yml snippet

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: bin/hello
    url: true
    events:
      - httpApi:
#          path: /{proxy+}
          path: /{any+}
          method: get
```

main.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/apex/gateway"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func inLambda() bool {
    if lambdaTaskRoot := os.Getenv("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"); lambdaTaskRoot != "" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)

    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "home page"})
    })
    r.GET("/hello-world", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "hello test completed successfully"})
    })

    return r
}

func main() {
    if inLambda() {
        fmt.Println("running aws lambda in aws")
        log.Fatal(gateway.ListenAndServe(":8080", setupRouter()))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("running aws lambda in local")
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", setupRouter()))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path: /{proxy+}` is correct.

Make sure you are using correct apex version. [apex README](https://github.com/apex/gateway#readme) states that you need to use apex v2 for HTTP API. You seem to be using v1 which supports REST API only.